# How can I tell what is calling one of my scope functions in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that has a template such as:

```
<div ng-show="isVisible()"> ... </div>
```

I've changed isVisible so it now simply returns true and does a console.log.

This directive is included a single time on my page, yet the log occurs 50+ times. I want to know what code is calling isVisible so many times. Is there any way to trace what is calling a function? The ACTUAL stack trace is completely useless, because angular appears to hide everything.
Is there some tool to figure out what non-angular code triggered a function call.

In some other cases I have data changing and I can't find where it's changing [it's not actually my code] and because the original code is in angular, I can't just use stack traces, or use watches or do my normal type of debugging.

here is the directive:

```
require('app').directive('kmFormLanguages', ["$q", function ($q) 
{
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: '<span ng-show="isVisible()"><span km-select multiple ng-model="binding" binding-type="string" placeholder="Available Languages" items="locales|orderBy:\'name\'" minimum="1"></span></span>',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      binding : '=ngModel',
    },   
    controller: ["$scope", "IStorage", "editFormUtility", function ($scope, storage, editFormUtility) {

      $scope.locales = [
        {identifier:"ar", name:"Arabic"  },   
        {identifier:"en", name:"English" }, 
        {identifier:"es", name:"Spanish" }, 
        {identifier:"fr", name:"French"  },   
        {identifier:"ru", name:"Russian" }, 
        {identifier:"zh", name:"Chinese" }
      ];   

      $scope.isVisible = function() {
        console.log('binding: ', $scope.binding);
        debugger;
        return $scope.binding!==undefined && $scope.binding!==null;
      }    
    }]   
  };
}])
```

and the html which uses it (no angular controls that are ancestors are shown):

```
<div ng-controller="editMeasure">
    [...]
    <div ng-show="!isLoading() && status!='hidden'">
        [...]
        <span km-form-languages ng-model="document.header.languages"></span>
```

Comment: do you wrap it with an `ng-repeat`? Each element of the ng-repeat runs the link directive function. Otherwise, check your `$watch` binding, they would surely be called too many times since you might not have enough idempotent callbacks.

Comment: $watch binding? I don't have any $watch calls in the directive, could it be something else? Also there is no ng-repeat for either the directive or the isVisible call.

Comment: Not necessarily in the directive itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say only from text. If you can post sample code, more accurate answers can be given.

But from what you have described, it seems that your function is being called as part of angular js

```
$digest or $compile
```

cycle.